# snowflake : copy into statement

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

when I add `VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS' FILES=('bad.csv')` in my copy into statement, I get error which error code is 002302. message as `SQL Compilation error: Expression  not supported within a VALIDATE expression`. I have a column which type is variant.
anybody has idea?
thanks

Comment: Please update your question with the full COPY statement

Comment: Can you share file format ,copy statement and snapshot of data to understand more details.

Answer (score 2):

the [help notes](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/copy-into-table.html#optional-parameters):

> VALIDATION_MODE does not support COPY statements that transform data during a load. If the parameter is specified, the COPY statement returns an error.

Which implies you are doing some form of JSON/Variant data processing in the COPY statements select. Which is valid without `VALIDATION_MODE = 'RETURN_ERRORS'`

So can you copy the data into a staging table, and do zero JSON process, to "just have raw data" which in a second command to merge/insert into a processed form?